# Can I use VPC Link to NLB with ACM imported private certificate?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc, aws-certificate-manager, nlb, sslengine

I've successfully got the api-gw taking to NLB (via VPC Link) then on to ALB then onto my ECS cluster running my apis.

To enable SSL between api-gw and ALB using private certs I've used the insecureSkipVerification tlsconfig.  The private certs were created by ACM-PCA in this test.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-extensions-integration-tls-config.html

However, what I want to do is import a private certificate, rather than use an AWS private CA created one.  When I do create my own certificate and import it into ACM and attached it to the load balancer, I get an SSL error:

**Execution failed due to....PKIX path building failed:...certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.**

This is the same error when you use a private cert without enabling: insecureSkipVerification.

Is using self managed private CA certs not an option at all with the api-gw?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue; in my case the issue was when I imported the custom certificate into ACM I didn't specify Certificate Chain. I was able to use the SSL certificate for the ALB but when integration to API Gateway I was getting the error. After I specified Certificate Chain I was able to use my custom SSL certificate (imported) with API Gateway without issues.

Specify a value for Certificate Chain:
[image: Specify a value for Certificate Chain]